# Inserting no repeating values in a sql table and get/input foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, foreign-keys

I will need a little help with this. I got two issues, that I've been working to solve for a couple of days.

First one is this: I am using **PrepairedStatement** to add a record from a form (of my application to a database, but have it so that the SQL code would only add the record if it doesn't find it in the database. I tried this:

```
 String sql= "INSERT INTO " + tableName + "(first_name,"+
            " last_name, tel, fax, email, agenda) VALUES"+
            "(?,?,?,?,?,?) SELECT * FROM (SELECT '"+fName+"', '"+lastName+"') AS tmp"+
            " WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT first_name FROM "+ tableName +" WHERE"+
            " first_name = '"+fName+"') LIMIT 1;";
```

This code returns me an SQL error that I can't find. Should I perhaps remove the "(?,?,?,?,?,?)" part? It worked beforehand on this:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO " + tableName +" (username, password)"+
              " SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Administrator', 'admin') AS tmp"+
              " WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT username FROM login WHERE "+
              " username = 'Administrator')LIMIT 1;";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

So, now the bigger issue that I can't wrap my mind around. I have 2 tables - a Students table and a Doctors table. They have a relationship where the **doctor_id** is a *foreign key* in the Students table and the *primary key* in the Doctors table. So because I am entering the details in a form, I get the strings from the text boxes and pass it to the function that adds these details into the table(s) like this:

```
    mrdb.addDoctorRecord("doctorsdetails", txtPDFirstName.getText(),
            txtPDLastName.getText(), txtTel.getText(),
            txtFax.getText(), txtEmail.getText(),txtAppointment.getText());
    mrdb.addStudentRecord ("Students",txtFName.getText(), txtMName.getText(),
    txtLName.getText(),txtareaInformationComments.getText(),
    Integer.parseInt(txtAge.getText(),10),Float.parseFloat(txtWaist.getText()), 
    Float.parseFloat(txtHeight.getText()),Float.parseFloat(txtWeight.getText()), 
    Integer.parseInt(txtClass.getText(), 10), txtSubClass.getText());
```

And so here is one of these functions (where I fill up a Student record):

```
public void addStudentRecord(String tableName, String fName, String midName, 
    String lastName, String comment, int age, float waist, float height, 
    float weight, int student_class, String subClass, String appointment){

    String sql = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + "(first_name, mid_name,"+
                "last_name, age, class, subclass, gender, doctor_id ,"+
                "diseases, more_info, height, weight, waist, appointment) "+
                "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    try{ 
    prepSTMT= conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    prepSTMT.setString(1, fName);
    prepSTMT.setString(2, midName);
    prepSTMT.setString(3, lastName);
    prepSTMT.setInt(4, age);
    prepSTMT.setInt(5, student_class);
    prepSTMT.setString(6, subClass);
    prepSTMT.setString(7, "m");
    prepSTMT.setInt(8, 3); // TODO update variable for FOREIGN KEY
    prepSTMT.setString(9, "b"); // TODO update variable
    prepSTMT.setString(10, comment);
    prepSTMT.setFloat(11, height);
    prepSTMT.setFloat(12, weight);
    prepSTMT.setFloat(13, waist);
    prepSTMT.setString(14, appointment);
    prepSTMT.executeUpdate();
    }catch(SQLException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

You can probably tell by the comment where I have inserted the foreign key (with a magic number (3)). I think to replace this with a variable, I will need to have someway to check what is the foreign key of the entry that I entered into the doctor's table. This is what I am confused and can't get my mind around. Do I have to do a query for Id and name of the doctor I entered previously? I need a hint.

Comment: Hi. Re "an SQL error that I can't find" What error? What error message? Where did you look? Google the error message without your particular names. Cut your code down until you don't get the error. Please act on [mcve]. Ask one question per question. PS LAST_INSERT_ID()

Comment: it's SQL syntax error, sorry I did not make it clear. It gives this:SELECT * FROM (SELECT '"+fName+"', '"+lastName+"') AS... on line 1. I am usually able to fix those but if it is complaining about the (? ? ? ? ? ?) part, well, i guess i will just need to cut security and go with normal statement that executes queries.

Answer (score 0):

For your first issue, why are you not using a left join?

For the second issue, even or-mappers like hibernate do a sql request to the database after an insert when the id is setby an id generator within the database even though the created intance with id is returned. Once you enable sql logging you could see the sql request.

If you consider using an or-mapper like hibernate you could use the hibernate id generator to generate the id's. By this the id is set by the client side and you would know it immediately.